# ASP.net Identity 2 sign in continue to use old password after changing password

Tags: owin, autofac, asp.net-identity-2, katana

I am using the Change Password functionality that visual studio generated for the accountcontroller. I am able to change the password without errors but when I go to login using the new password, I get a login error but if I use the old password, it works.

If I restart the app then the newly changed password takes effect. I am also using Autofac, may be I am not configuring the container correctly.

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new ApplicationDataContext(connectionString)).InstancePerLifetimeScope();

        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf();
        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>().AsSelf();
        builder.Register(c => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(c.Resolve<ApplicationDataContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.Register(c => new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(c.Resolve<ApplicationDataContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces();
        builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).As<IAuthenticationManager>();
        builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
        {
            DataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("Application​")
        });

        builder.Register(c => new ApplicationOAuthProvider(publicClientId, c.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>())).As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();
```

Any help will be much appreciated.

Thanks

--------UPDATED----------

ContanierConfig.cs

```
public static void Configure(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        const string publicClientId = "self";

        // ContainerConfig Config
        var connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DefaultConnection"].ConnectionString;
        var elasticsearchUrl = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchUrl"];
        var elasticSearchName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ElasticSearchName"];

        var builder = new ContainerBuilder();

        builder.Register(c => new BimDataContext(connectionString)).InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationUserManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<ApplicationRoleManager>().AsSelf().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(c.Resolve<BimDataContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new RoleStore<IdentityRole>(c.Resolve<BimDataContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => HttpContext.Current.GetOwinContext().Authentication).As<IAuthenticationManager>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.Register(c => new IdentityFactoryOptions<ApplicationUserManager>
        {
            DataProtectionProvider = new DpapiDataProtectionProvider("Application​")
        }).InstancePerRequest(); ;

        builder.RegisterType<SimpleRefreshTokenProvider>().As<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<AuthRepository>().As<IAuthRepository>().InstancePerRequest();

        builder.Register(c => new ApplicationOAuthProvider(
            publicClientId, 
            c.Resolve<ApplicationUserManager>(), 
            c.Resolve<IAuthRepository>()))
            .As<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>().InstancePerRequest();

        // Register your Web API controllers.
        builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly()).InstancePerRequest();

        // UoW registration: being explicit
        builder.RegisterType<UnitOfWork>().As<IUnitOfWork>().InstancePerRequest();

        // Repositories registration
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ClientRepository).Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest(); 

        // Services registration
        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ClientService).Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterAssemblyTypes(typeof(ClientSearchService).Assembly)
            .AsImplementedInterfaces()
            .InstancePerRequest();

        builder.RegisterType<IfcFileImportTask>().As<IIfcFileImportTask>().InstancePerRequest();
        builder.RegisterType<COBieFileImportTask>().As<ICOBieFileImportTask>().InstancePerRequest();

        // Hangfire registration
        builder.RegisterType<BackgroundJobClient>().As<IBackgroundJobClient>().InstancePerRequest();

        // OPTIONAL: Register the Autofac filter provider.
        builder.RegisterWebApiFilterProvider(config);

        // Set the dependency resolver to be Autofac.
        var container = builder.Build();
        JobActivator.Current = new AutofacJobActivator(container);
        config.DependencyResolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);
    }
```

Startup.Auth.Cs

```
public partial class Startup
    {
        public static OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions OAuthOptions { get; private set; }

        public static string PublicClientId { get; private set; }

        // For more information on configuring authentication, please visit http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=301864
        public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCors(Microsoft.Owin.Cors.CorsOptions.AllowAll);

            // Configure the db context and user manager to use a single instance per request
            //app.CreatePerOwinContext(BimDataContext.Create);
            //app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);

            // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
            // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
            app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
            app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

            // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
            PublicClientId = "self";
            var oAuthAuthorizationServerProvider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope().Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();
        var authenticationTokenProvider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope().Resolve<IAuthenticationTokenProvider>();
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = oAuthAuthorizationServerProvider,
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5),
            RefreshTokenProvider = authenticationTokenProvider,
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false,
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };

            // Enable the application to use bearer tokens to authenticate users
            app.UseOAuthBearerTokens(OAuthOptions);
        }
```

Getting error

```
"value cannot be null. parameter name context autofac" on line var oAuthAuthorizationServerProvider = GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver.GetRequestLifetimeScope().Resolve<IOAuthAuthorizationServerProvider>();
```

Answer (score 1):

I was missing a key component of oauth2, the solution to this problem is refresh_tokens. On change password, invalidate the refresh token and force user to log out.

http://bitoftech.net/2014/07/16/enable-oauth-refresh-tokens-angularjs-app-using-asp-net-web-api-2-owin/

Comment: I have implemented refresh tokens but they wont solve the problem. Access_Token needs to expire on change password activity.

Answer (score 1):

If using ASP.NET (this includes MVC and Web API, Web Forms, etc) and AutoFac you should register all your components using the extension method `.InstancePerRequest()`. The only exception is for components that are thread safe and where you do not have to worry about errors/unexpected results occurring from one request accessing the same (stale) data as another. An example might be a Factory or a Singleton.

Example of use on a line of code:

```
builder.Register(c => new UserStore<ApplicationUser>(c.Resolve<ApplicationDataContext>())).AsImplementedInterfaces().InstancePerRequest();
```

This ensures that every new incoming Http Request will get its own copy of that implementation (resolved and injected hopefully via an interface). Autofac will also cleanup the Disposable instances at the end of each request.

This is the behavior you need. It ensures that there is no cross request interference (like one request manipulating data on a shared dbcontext on another request). It also ensures that data is not stale as it is cleaned up after each request ends.

See [the Autofac documentation](http://docs.autofac.org/en/latest/lifetime/instance-scope.html#instance-per-request) for more details (here an excerpt).

> #### Instance Per Request
>
> Some application types naturally lend themselves to “request” type semantics, for example ASP.NET web forms and MVC applications. In these application types, it’s helpful to have the ability to have a sort of “singleton per request.”
>
> Instance per request builds on top of instance per matching lifetime scope by providing a well-known lifetime scope tag, a registration convenience method, and integration for common application types. Behind the scenes, though, it’s still just instance per matching lifetime scope.

Changing your DI definitions above to include this should resolve your issues (I think based on what you have provided). If not then it might be a problem with your Identity registration in which case you should post that code so it can be scrutinized.